# How to record the sequence of events effectively when there is a logical flow runs over various event notifications?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, gui, event-programming

Let me explain what I mean **there is a logical flow runs over various event notifications** based on our web app, which is event-driven and it is quite common in my opinion.

1. User clicks a button to trigger some action and a web request. The event handler here is bound to some UI action.
2. Web app updates UI based on the request result, which may invite user to take further action. The event handler here is bound to the web request result.
3. Web server may further process the request and send out further event notification to the web app through websocket and the web app will update UI accordingly. The event handler here is bound to websocket messages.

In the above steps, a single click event at the first step will trigger a sequence of events to happen and the their event handlers to be called. Without a good document our team has a hard time to figure out why this event happens, why this event handler is called? But a "good" document is always something we all know it is important but we don't have time to do.

The indirectness of event-driven model does make the documentation harder. So any suggestion to record the sequence of events effectively and up-to-date ?

Comment: What do you mean “record the sequence of events?” Do you mean at runtime, programmatically? Or are you talking about a document of some kind?

Comment: I want to find who triggers this event, why is this event handler called. Except for document, is there any other way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Generating a transaction ID at step 1 may not be precise because many transactions may overlap or the user using the back button might confuse the process or restart several times the same process. But it is still the cheapest way to keep track of multiple events. It is also normal that complex processes have multiple transactions and transaction IDs at the same time which may be generated by the client and the different servers involved. Moreover there are many tools that help administrators analyse all the logs correlating the log lines by one or more transaction IDs.